# Best way to organize and run robot test across multiple platforms

Tags: cucumber, robotframework, ui-automation

New to this. Trying to figure out the best way of organizing tests that have to run across multiple platforms is it possible to have one test case that can point to keywords for different platforms. Do tags work in this scenario so that I could tag a particular test with 4 platform tags and somehow configure it to look at the first tag and go to the appropriate keyword for that tag / test case combination?

So that I could use the following example test case and run it 4 times, one for each platform I need to test:

Test Case

```
Given I can log in to my application
When I select the thing
Then I see the other thing
```

And not have to have 4 test separate tests cases one for each platform like:

```
Given I can log in to my application in native iOS app

Given I can log in to my application in native android app

Given I can log in to my application in native desktop app

Given I can log in to my application in native web app
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to use a variable to identify which platform-specific library to import. For example, the import statement might look like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ${platform}Library.py
```

Then, you can create files named **IOSLibrary.py**, **Android.py**, etc, and then specify which one to load like this:

```
$ robot -v platform:IOS tests
$ robot -v platform:Android tests
```